# Select Query by array values

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I have an  array of ids, I have to select from table for each value of array , i can get it by one by one in `for loop`,

```
SELECT  point, privacy FROM `tableName` WHERE id='1403176452487620892'and status=1
```

but the problem is that array size is 100, i need a single query not 100.

Comment: What language is this coming from? Java?

Comment: @AlvinThompson i am using Scala

Comment: Yep, loop and bind the values through the JDBC driver.

Comment: Scala on the JVM, right?

Comment: Not **that** similar, but you're running it on the JVM so you're using the JDBC driver. That means you can bind the values no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use:

```
SELECT  point, privacy FROM `tableName` WHERE status=1 and id in(?,?,?...)
```

Yes, it's ridiculously long, but if one query is what you need...

Comment: `Use a for loop for that as well` your comment in that post, sorry i didn't get it

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti: but now you do?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti: sorry, what did you mean by, "means its not a correct way to use `IN` my case"?

Comment: did i have to use your query or not

Comment: Yep. No alternative in JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :

```
   $ids = join(',',$ids);  
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

Comment: Is the array of IDs in the DB? MySQL can't do `for` loops, can it?

Comment: `$ids = join(',',$ids);`  not familiar with this syntax did it convert it to comma delimated string

Comment: Yes,it convert it to comma delimated string.

Comment: @AlvinThompson its not in db

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti: so use a `for` loop in whatever language it's coming from to construct that huge `in` statement with all those values, and bind the values from the array. Unless you're using Oracle, having 100 values in your `in` statement presents no problem.

Comment: @AlvinThompson means its not a correct way to use `IN` my case

Comment: Do you mean `concat_ws`? `join` seems like an unlikely name for a function since it's a keyword.

Comment: @AlvinThompson i am thinking of using `in` and reducing my array size to 20, hope it will not create any problem

Comment: ...or is that some other language?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti: no need to reduce. It'll work fine. You don't need to type out all that yourself. Use a `for` loop for that as well. That way the array can be any arbitrary size. I've used `in` clauses with hundreds of values before.

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti: As I mentioned, Oracle is the only one with a limit on `in` clause size (99 IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$str = implode(",", $array);
$sql = "SELECT  point, privacy FROM `tableName` WHERE id in ($str) and status=1";
```